# Preg matching imgur.com links

Tags: php, regex

I need to `preg_match` links to imgur.com service.
So, my code is:

```
if (!preg_match("/(http|https)\:\/\/[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}
(\/\$_POST['request'])) { ... }
```

How to make it work only with links like those?

```
http://imgur.com/aBc1
  https://imgur.com/a/aBc1
http://www.imgur.com/a/aBc1
  https://www.imgur.com/a/aBc1
http://imgur.com/gallery/aBc1
  https://imgur.com/gallery/aBc1
http://i.imgur.com/aBc1.png(.jpg,.jpeg,.gif)
  https://i.imgur.com/aBc1.png(.jpg,.jpeg,.gif)
```

Comment: Do you care about capturing groups at all?  Meaning, do you want to have access to any of the values from the URL?  Or do you just need to know that it is or isn't an imgur URL?

Comment: @PatrickQ, last one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do:

```
/(http|https)\:\/\/[a-z]{0,4}[\.]*imgur+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}\/[a-zA-Z0-9]+(\/)*[a-zA-Z0-9]*[\.]*(jpg|png|jpeg|gif)*/g
```

- `(http|https)` : checking for `http` or `https` in the URL
- `[a-z\.]{0,4}` : checking for `www./i.` etc.
- `(jpg|png|jpeg|gif)*` to detect your given formats (if any)

Live demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/JRv663/1/)

Answer (score 1):

This pattern will match all of the URLs that you provided

```
/http(s)?\:\/\/(.*\.)?imgur.com\/.*/
```

Explanation:

- `http`  Match the literal characters 'http'
- `(s)?`  Optionally match at most one 's'
- `\:\/\/`  Match the literal characters '://'
- `(.*\.)?`  Optionally match any amount of any characters followed by a period/dot
- `imgur.com\/`  Match 'imgur.com/'
- `.*`  Match any number of any additional characters

[DEMO](https://regexr.com/3h0n4)

Comment: Thanks a lot, buddy